# What happened to the variations tool? (Elgar will be most displeased!)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I've just updated to CS6 and find that my old friend "variations" is no longer there! It was very useful for quick, small colour corrections or to use for a suggestion before the image was sent to the retouching department/services. I would like to know why it was decided to remove it, and on whose authority!

Answer (score 4):

On **Adobe's** authority as it is their product. As of why, you'll have to ask them, not us.

> As the previous post indicates, the Image > Adjustment > Variations
>   menu item and function has been dropped in all 64-bit versions of
>   Photoshop from day one, ever since Photoshop CS4 Windows and CS5
>   Macintosh (there was no 64-bit version of CS4 for the Mac).   For the
>   time being, at least, there's no Macintosh 32-bit version of the CS6
>   beta, so the Variations will not be available to you in CS6 beta if
>   you're on a Mac.

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/message/4346007